# Selecting records with duplicate number in one column, and a unique string in another

Tags: sql, database, postgresql

I have a Postgres table of records that include many new Filed accounts with a reg_number, and many Filed accounts that are now Finalized with the same reg_number.

I can't query by date or row number because of inconsistencies.

I need to be able to select:
Any Filed rows - that have not yet been Finalized and,
Any Finalized rows but, not their original 'filed' row.

Source Data Table

```
reg_num   |  file_final   |  otherCols  
1234      |   filed       |   foo  
1234      |   final       |   foo  
1235      |   filed       |   foo  
1218      |   filed       |   foo  
1111      |   final       |   foo  
1235      |   final       |   foo
```

Desired Select:

```
reg_num   |  file_final  |  otherCols  
1234      |   final      |   foo  
1218      |   filed      |   foo  
1111      |   final      |   foo  
1235      |   final      |   foo
```

I have tried a number of combinations of SELECT DISTINCT ON and JOINS but, am stuck.
The two pertinent fields are shown above and the overall table has about 25 other columns,
which I need to be able to select from.

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks!
Some queries I've tried (among 10+) include:

SELECT *
FROM ca_enforce
WHERE reg_number IN
(
    SELECT DISTINCT ON (reg_number) reg_number
    WHERE file_final = 'Final' OR file_final = 'Filed'
    GROUP BY reg_number
);

Another:

SELECT DISTINCT ON reg_number,
    id,
    col3,
    col4,
    file_final,
    col6,
    col7,
    reg_number
  WHERE file_final = 'Final'
  FROM my_table
  ORDER BY file_final;

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The union techniques force PostGreSQL to pass twice through the data.

With an index on the reg_num column the following query should perform faster:

```
select reg_num, file_final, otherCols
from t t1
where file_final = 'final' or not exists (
  select *
  from t t2
  where t2.reg_num = t1.reg_num and t2.file_final = 'final');
```

Comment: Thanks to both responses. I accepted this one since it gave the results with the least tweaking... and that only because I had to change both 't' table references to the same schema.table name. Thank you!, this helped reveal a huge defect in the data source's methodology where they misclassified about 30% of the records.

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like two queries that can be union all'd together:

```
--get all of the filed records that don't have final records.
select reg_num
from my_table
where reg_num not in (
  select reg_num
  from my_table
  where final_file = 'final'
)
where final_file = 'file'

union all
--get all of the final records.
select reg_num
from my_table
where file_final = 'final'
```

Answer (score 0):

```
select reg_num,file_final,othercols
from table_name
where reg_num not in (
              select reg_num
              from table_name
               where final_file = 'final'
                     )
union all
select reg_num,file_final,othercols
from table_name
where file_final = 'final'
```